# Conjunctive "cum" + indicative in Menaechmi

Tags: grammar-identification, conjunction, subordinate-clause

In the last scene of *Menaechmi*, Plautus wrote

> Pol profecto haud est dissimilis, meam **cum** formam noscito. (Line 1065)

Henry T. Riley's [translation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0101%3Aact%3D5%3Ascene%3D9) gives:

> Troth, it really is not unlike, **so far as** I know my own form.

Conjunctive **cum** has too many meanings, and what I can remember is [**cum** + *ind.* = *when*]. I think it's not correct here (*when I know my form*), but I can't find the translation *so far as* in Lewis & Short's dictionary, neither in Allen & Greenough's grammar.

How is **cum** used here?

Comment: Do you have an edition that prints *nescito* instead of [*noscito*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnoscito)? Based on your comments I assume it's just a typo, but I don't want to edit if that's part of your question.

Comment: @brianpck it's a typo and I corrected it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer will be about the printed text:

> Pol profecto haud est dissimilis, meam quom formam noscito.

*quom* is just an archaic spelling of the conjunction and preposition *cum*, so your question still stands. (*noscito*, though, is a straightforward 1st person singular indicative present, whereas *nescito* is a future imperative of *nescio*.)

The [Lewis & Short entry for the conjunction *cum*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DCum2) is vast. Though it is often used in temporal clauses, it has many other meanings.

I initially proposed a causal meaning: "since, because, given that." Though this causal meaning usually takes the subjunctive in classical prose, anteclassical authors (including Plautus) frequently use the indicative (see meaning II.A.1).

As Sebastian pointed out in the comments, though, *cum* with the present indicative can also have an "indefinite temporal meaning" that is more like "si" (i.e. "if").

I think this latter sense is most appropriate here, though obviously we shouldn't treat this as a strict separation of meanings. You could thus translate as follows:

> By Pollux, it is indeed not different at all, if I know my own appearance.

Comment: The big L & S entry starts out, by the way, with the definition: “The time designated by cum being indefinite, when, if, whenever, always with indic. [⋯] cum with pres. indic., often equivalent to si” (I. A. 1. a.) – which in my opinion would also fit this context.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel You're right--I skipped too quickly through the "temporal" senses. I think that meaning is even more appropriate and have changed my answer to reflect that. Thanks!